# Create 'global' variable for each test in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, global-variables

I'm looking to add a `Session` variable to track cookies and other information for each RSpec test. I'd like to have access to `Session` from a variety of files/classes, but want a single `Session` created and updated per test case.

My initial thinking was to create a `Session` class, initialize it in `before(:each)`. That gives each spec access to the `Session`, but classes called by the spec do not have access to it.

What's the best approach to accomplish this?

Here's some sample code -

my requests wrapper:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'faraday'
require 'securerandom'

# A custom exception class used by the Faraday wrapper
class RequestBuilderException < StandardError
  def initialize(msg = 'Exception during RequestBuilder', exception_type = 'requestbuilder')
    @exception_type = exception_type
    super(msg)
  end
end

# A Faraday API requests wrapper class.
class RequestBuilder
  attr_accessor :conn

  def initialize(host)
    @conn = Faraday::Connection.new host
  end

  def get(url: nil, expected_statuses: [200, 202, 204], **options)
    request(http_method: 'get', url: url, expected_statuses: expected_statuses, params: options[:params],
            headers: options[:headers], cookies: options[:cookies], body: options[:body])
  end

  def post(url: nil, expected_statuses: [200, 202, 204], **options)
    request(http_method: 'post', url: url, expected_statuses: expected_statuses, params: options[:params],
            headers: options[:headers], cookies: options[:cookies], body: options[:body])
  end

...

  # rubocop:disable Metrics/CyclomaticComplexity
  def request(http_method: nil, url: nil, expected_statuses: [], **options)
    response = @conn.public_send(http_method) do |request|
      request.url url

      if options.key?(:headers) && options[:headers]
        options[:headers].each do |name, value|
          request.headers[name] = value
        end
      end

      if options.key?(:params) && options[:params]
        options[:params].each do |name, value|
          request.params[name] = value
        end
      end

      request.body = options[:body] if options[:body]
    end
    sanitize_response(response, expected_statuses)
  end
  
  def sanitize_response(response, exepected_statuses)
    raise RequestBuilderException, 'No response received.' unless response

    unless exepected_statuses.include? response.status
      raise RequestBuilderException.new "Received unexpected status code #{response.status}, \
      expected status in #{exepected_statuses}", 'RequestBuilder.status'
    end

    response
  end
end
```

Then I have two classes, `Students` and `Courses` that leverage the `requests` class

```
require 'framework/util/request'


class StudentsApi
  attr_accessor :conn, :authorization_header, :user_info, :accounts_register_response

  def initialize(host, authorization)
    @conn = RequestBuilder.new(host)
    @authorization_header = authorization.auth_string
    @user_info = nil
    @accounts_register_response = nil
  end


  def accounts_register(expected_statuses: [201], **options)
    user_hash = {
      first_name: options.fetch(:first_name, nil),
      last_name: options.fetch(:last_name, nil),
      email: options.fetch(:email, nil),
      password: options.fetch(:password, nil),
      remember_me: options.fetch(:remember_me, nil),
      zip_code: options.fetch(:zip_code, nil),
      source: options.fetch(:source, nil)
    }

    headers = { 'Authorization': authorization_header,
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'Accept': 'application/json' }
    params = { 'user': user_hash}

    @accounts_register_response = conn.post(url: '/accounts/register', headers: headers,
                                            params: params, expected_statuses: expected_statuses)

    @user_info = User.from_response(@accounts_register_response)
    @user_info
  end

  def accounts_login(email:, password:, accept: 'application/json', **_options)
    headers = { 'Authorization': authorization_header, 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Accept': accept }
    params = { 'email': email, 'password': password }

    conn.post(url: '/accounts/login', headers: headers, params: params)
  end
end
```

```
class CoursesApi
  attr_accessor :conn, :authorization_header, :user_info, :accounts_register_response

  def initialize(host, authorization)
    @conn = RequestBuilder.new(host)
    @authorization_header = authorization.auth_string
    @user_info = nil
  end


  def egister_course(email:, accept: 'application/json', **_options)
    headers = { 'Authorization': authorization_header, 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Accept': accept }
    params = { 'email': email}

    conn.post(url: '/register_course', headers: headers, params: params)
  end
end
```

And finally, I have rspec that tests that a newly signed up Student can register for a course (which requires email + cookie, the cookie is sent on as a `Set-Cookie` on the response for Student.accounts_login

```
require 'framework/students/api'
require 'framework/courses/api'

RSpec.describe 'Creating New Student' do
  before(:all) do
    @new_student = StudentsApi.new_user(@user_session)
  end

  it 'allows students to register and login' do
    expect(@new_student.accounts_register_response.status).to eq(201)
    expect(@new_student.accounts_login.status).to eq(200)
  end

  it 'allows students to sign up for a course' do
    expect(@new_student.accounts_register_response.status).to eq(201)
    expect(@new_student.accounts_login.status).to eq(200) # need to store cookies from this response
    course = CoursesApi.new(name: 'Math')
    expect(course.register_course(email: @new_student.email)).to eq(201) # requires the cookies to be sent
  end

end
```

Comment: every session is unique per request, e.g. every `it {}` clause. do you need to store all of them, or only last, or every successful test?

Comment: `before(:each) { @session = ... }` ?

Comment: @zhisme every session is unique per test (every `it`) though inside a single test multiple classes might be used which should all have access to read/write the session

Comment: @TomLord when I tried that, classes that are called inside each test did not have access to `@session`.

Comment: What do you mean by "classes called inside each test"? It's much easier to understand what you're trying to do with a concrete example. It's probably a bad idea to define a totally *global* variable that can be accessed literally anywhere, but if that's really what you want to do, then: `before(:each) { $session = ... }`

Comment: @TomLord fair enough. Each test makes a series of requests using faraday to external APIs. I wanted to share a 'Session' for each test such that all requests could read the cookies from previous requests. The 'requests' are made using a `Request` wrapper class around Faraday

Comment: It sounds like you could eliminate the need for a global variable by dependency injecting some `cookies` into the `Request` class. But once again, without a concrete example (actual code), I cannot provide a concrete solution (actual code).

Comment: @TomLord added code that hopefully explains what I'm doing. The RSpec isn't used for unit testing, but rather to chain API requests together. `Students` and `Courses` are classes that use the `Request` wrapper class, and that's why I thought of creating a global variable (since global vars are limited in scope to the individual rspec test)

Comment: So the problem seems to be that you're establishing new connections for each and every request, yet simultaneously expecting cookies to be persisted between requests. Within the `RequestBuilder`, does the `@conn` object currently persist the cookies as you'd expect? If so, then perhaps the missing trick is to **dependency inject** a connection into the `StudentApi` and `CoursesApi` classes.

Comment: For example, you can do: `def initialize(host, authorization, conn: RequestBuilder.new(host))`. Then after performing the student login, you pass the `conn` variable back into the other API(s) to maintain the same session.